# pack dataframe columns to list in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to pack pandas DataFrame columns in one column containing lists. Example:

For

```
>>>df
    a   b   c
0  81  88   1
1  42   7  23
2   8  37  63
3  18  22  20
```

make list column:

```
    list_col
0  [81,88,1]
1  [42,7,23]
2  [8,37,63]
3  [18,22,20]
```

If I try

> > > df.apply(list,axis=1)

python returns same DataFrame.

In case I try

```
>>> df.apply(lambda r:{'list_col':list(r)},axis=1)
    a   b   c
0 NaN NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN NaN
3 NaN NaN NaN
```

is not working.

Even brute method

```
>>> df['list_col'] = ''
>>> for i in df.index:
    df.ix[i,'list_col'] = list(df.ix[i,df.columns[:-1]])
```

returns error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#45>", line 2, in <module>
    df.ix[i,'list_col'] = list(df.ix[i,df.columns[:-1]])
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 88, in __setitem__
    self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 158, in _setitem_with_indexer
    len(self.obj[labels[0]]) == len(value) or len(plane_indexer[0]) == len(value)):
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

The only working method I found is:

```
df['list_col'] = df.apply(lambda r:{df.columns[0]:list(r)}, axis=1)[df.columns[0]]
```

This gives me what I want but maybe there is more straight way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just assign the column as a list on `df.values` will do:

```
df['list_col'] = list(df.values)

df
    a   b   c      list_col
0  81  88   1   [81, 88, 1]
1  42   7  23   [42, 7, 23]
2   8  37  63   [8, 37, 63]
3  18  22  20  [18, 22, 20]
```

Comment: Great! Exactly what I need. Thanks. But still why df.apply(list,axis=1) is not working? It's confusing.

Comment: `df.apply` is to each value in array, so `df.apply(list, axis=1)` is equivalent to: apply `list()` on each value in the array, ie. `81 = [81], 88 = [88], ...` individually. So it will have no effects.

Comment: Actually no. apply works with entire row (if axis parameter = 1). If you make df.apply(sum,axis=1) you will receive sum of entire row. Additionally, try df.apply(lambda r: ','.join([str(e) for e in r]),axis=1) and you will get one result for each row.

Comment: that's only because sum will take a list as an argument, whereas list only take the individual value

Comment: The reason why df.apply(list, 1) fails is because df.apply tries to cast the result to a DataFrame or Series object at the end, as this is often the result you're looking for. There's no way to tell it to leave the results as is without using an iterator or generator approach. A more verbose alternative using df.apply is `df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series({"list_col": list(x)}), 1)`, which works around the simplification problem by returning a series of lists.

Comment: @mobiusklein, I agree but I do believe that's because function `sum` will take array elements whereas `list` only takes iterable element.

Comment: @Anzel, I can't see why `sum` is applicable here. The OP is asking for a method of aggregating values into a list structure, not a numerical operation. From your first comment, it looks like you're arguing that `list()` in Python takes more than one parameter. It doesn't. The behavior you're attributing to apply, element-wise operations, is what df.applymap does. Can you clarify what you mean, please?

Comment: I think my presentation skills need improving, I only refer to `sum` as @user3364098 mentioned in comment about why `sum` works on `apply` but `list` doesn't. my first comment was trying to make a point how `list` doesn't change the element in the row array, I guess I didn't explain it in a clear way.

Comment: @mobiusklein, but you are right, i should have explained as `list([81, 88, ...]) == [81, 88, ...]` as the `axis=1`

Comment: @Anzel: Your solution works like a charm. Just to be sure my understanding is correct: list builds from the ndarray, which is the converted to a pandas series of (nd) arrays from this list? It was bugging me that list would apply to each row of an ndarray without reason, while it is not actually happening, if I am right?

Comment: @AndoJurai, technically speaking it's not an ndarray, it's an array of LIST of row values, eg. `Array(List of Row(values))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vectorized approach, which is very similar to [@Anzel's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26780402/5741205):

```
In [55]: df
Out[55]:
    a   b   c
0  81  88   1
1  42   7  23
2   8  37  63
3  18  22  20

In [56]: df['list_col'] = df.values.tolist()

In [57]: df
Out[57]:
    a   b   c      list_col
0  81  88   1   [81, 88, 1]
1  42   7  23   [42, 7, 23]
2   8  37  63   [8, 37, 63]
3  18  22  20  [18, 22, 20]
```

**Timing against 4M rows DF:**

```
In [69]: df.shape
Out[69]: (4000000, 3)

In [70]: %timeit list(df.values)
1 loop, best of 3: 2.04 s per loop

In [71]: %timeit df.values.tolist()
1 loop, best of 3: 993 ms per loop
```