# Making lists from pandas.dataframe.iloc slice doesn't work while pandas.dataframe.values slice work

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I want to agregate columns from a dataframe into a new columns

So I used:

```
newdataframe["agregate1"]=list(df.iloc[:,0:4])
```

but it doesn't work.
It returns an ["intensity_x"] list (with x as column index), these strings being the names of my dataframe columns.

While

```
newdataframe["agregate1"]=list(df.iloc[0,0:4])
```

will return data such as

[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2920000000.0, 2830000000.0, 3030000000.0, 0.0, 2980000000.0, 3000000000.0].

It is actually important since I can't retrieve correctly my data and it seems like a bug, or I am missing something important.

By reading:
[pack dataframe columns to list in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26779972/pack-dataframe-columns-to-list-in-pandas)

I circumvented the problem by using df.values instead of iloc, still I don't understand what is the problem with using "whole slices", only getting headers instead. This is strange. Thanks

Comment: `df.iloc[:,0:4]` will return a df, the iterable for a df are the columns, which is  what you observe, are you after `(df.iloc[:,0:4].values.tolist())`? this will return a 2-d np array in a list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If use:

```
df1 = df.iloc[:,0:4]
```

output is `DataFrame`.

If:

```
df2 = df.iloc[0,0:4]
```

Output is `Series` - first `row` in `df` and columns `1:4`.

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  4  7  1  5  7
1  2  5  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  3

df1 = df.iloc[:,0:4]
print (df1)
   A  B  C  D
0  1  4  7  1
1  2  5  8  3
2  3  6  9  5

df2 = df.iloc[0,0:4]
print (df2)
A    1
B    4
C    7
D    1
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Then you can use [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) if need output as `numpy array`:

```
print (df1.values)
[[1 4 7 1]
 [2 5 8 3]
 [3 6 9 5]]
```

If need output `list` of `lists`, use:

```
print (df1.values.tolist())
[[1, 4, 7, 1], [2, 5, 8, 3], [3, 6, 9, 5]]
```

If need list in new column:

```
df['new'] = df.iloc[:,0:4].values.tolist()
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F           new
0  1  4  7  1  5  7  [1, 4, 7, 1]
1  2  5  8  3  3  4  [2, 5, 8, 3]
2  3  6  9  5  6  3  [3, 6, 9, 5]

df['new'] = list(df.iloc[:,0:4].values)
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F           new
0  1  4  7  1  5  7  [1, 4, 7, 1]
1  2  5  8  3  3  4  [2, 5, 8, 3]
2  3  6  9  5  6  3  [3, 6, 9, 5]
```

Comment: Ok, that's very clear, thanks a lot. I didn't know that a list on a dataframe will get its columns names, actually. Nice to  know.